# Flask + apache Internal Server Error when making request or database

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, flask

I'm using apache with flask and when opening /login (I use database here) i get Internal server Error
As database im using sqlite and python library sqlite3

```
DATABASE = '../../var/www/flask/database'
```

connecting database function :

```
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
```

login code

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.cookies.get("name"):
        return render_template("home.html",name=request.cookies.get('name'))
    g.db = connect_db() 
    cur = g.db.execute('SELECT email, password, name, confirmed FROM users')
    for row in cur.fetchall(): 
            if row[0] == request.form['email'] and row[1] ==   hashlib.sha224(request.form['password']).hexdigest() and row[3] == 1:
                resp = make_response(redirect(host + "/home"))
                resp.set_cookie("name",row[2])
                resp.set_cookie("password",row[1])
                return resp
    return redirect(host)
```

here is my .wsgi code

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/flask/')

from routes import app as application
```

and here is my app tree
 
flask - static - (css js etc.)
      - templates - (jinja2 template)
      - database.db
      - min.wsgi
      - routes.py (app)

here is routes.com.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.test
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/min.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/flask/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What error was logged in your Apache error log?

Comment: And what is `DATABASE` set to?

Comment: Do *not* use a relative path for `DATABASE`; WSGI sets a working directory you probably do not have write access to.

Comment: Finaly i set path for databse and it works. Thank you @MartijnPieters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an *absolute path* for your `DATABASE` value.

The `mod_wsgi` module will set a different current working directory for your app, one you most likely do not have access to. Even if you did give your Apache process write access to that directory, you don't want to end up changing a seemingly harmless setting elsewhere for it all to stop working again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of wrong indentation in `login` function? It would caused some very other error log probably, but it's my first guess when I'm looking at code formatted in wrong way (even if it's just wrong copy-paste).

Comment: It's wrong copy past. Normaly using flask 127.0.0.1:5000 server it runs normal.